# How to match an overlapping pattern multiple times using RegExp

Tags: javascript, regex

Is there a way with a RegExp that given the regex /aa/g (or similar) it matches two times the string "aaa"? Given that the first match is the first two a's, and the second match is the last two a's.

Something like this:

- Match 1: 'aa'a
- Match 2: a'aa'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can change the `lastIndex` of `reg` to the `index+1`

```js
let str = "aaa",
  reg = /aa/g,
  next = reg.exec(str),
  res = [];
while (next) {
  res.push(next[0]);
  reg.lastIndex = next.index + 1;
  next = reg.exec(str);
}
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can capture two **a**'s inside lookahead and then go back & match one **a** character.

```js
    let pattern = /(?=(a{2}))a/g;
    let resultMatches = [];
    let match;
    let stringToCheck = 'aaa';

    while ((match = pattern.exec(stringToCheck)) !== null)
        resultMatches.push(match[1]);

    console.log(resultMatches);
```

> Using 'aaa' as input returns  [ 'aa', 'aa' ], whereas using 'aaaa' as input would return [ 'aa', 'aa', 'aa' ]