# regex match multiple patterns from previous characters

Tags: regex

have a question for you.

Simply:

let`s have a string:

```
'aaa'
```

and regex pattern:

```
/aa/g
```

I would expected a two results, first + second a, and second + third a.

Instead, I got only first two a`s (I though regex will not skip second 'a' perfoming second (or third.. etc) match).

So, how to write regex that will return two matches ('aa' (1. + 2. a) and 'aa' (2. + 3. a)) ?

Thanks!

Comment: Let me know your programming language in case you have problems implementing the code in the mentioned dupe.

Comment: `(?:(?=(aa)).)`   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49744804/how-to-match-an-overlapping-pattern-multiple-times-using-regexp

Comment: no problems anymore, ty so much for the answer, duplicate redirect helped aswell